# What is the relation between PHP and XML?

Tags: php, xml

I'm learning about PHP and web coding. 
Specifically, the PHP book I'm using that covers PHP 5.3 (by Matt Doyle and published by Wrox), says:

> XML ... lets you create text documents that can hold  data in a structured way...
>   XML isn't really a language but rather a sepcification for creating your own markup languages...

Wikipedia says of XML:

> As of 2009, hundreds of XML-based languages have been developed,[8] including RSS, Atom, SOAP, and XHTML. XML-based formats have become the default for many office-productivity tools, including Microsoft Office (Office Open XML), OpenOffice.org and LibreOffice (OpenDocument), and Apple's iWork.[9] XML has also been employed as the base language for communication protocols, such as XMPP.

It sounds like XML is more like a protocol, a standard for allowing compuers to communicate and share information.

So XML is like a grammar I can use to create a markup language, but the language I create only formats data?

I want help defining  the relationship between PHP and XML.
When during the processesing of PHP and HTML does XML get parsed?

Comment: What does XML has to do with PHP specifically???

Comment: XML is a way to structure data. You can use PHP to process data formated as XML (e.g. through the SAX or DOM APIs), but that's it. There is not special connection between PHP and XML (not more than between Python and XML or Java and XML or...).

Comment: @PeeHaa - that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: When I was learning XML (back in the last millennium), and looking past the hype of the time, XML was essentially seen as an alternative to comma-separated-values (CSV) files, and I still find it useful to think in those terms. Where CSV files are well suited to storing/carrying 2 dimensional data, XML is well suited to tree structured data, but element names (XML) are analogous to column headings (CSV) and CSV, like XML, is primarily about defining a common *syntax* to allow the data to be interpreted by a computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML is not a grammar (that's another thing entirely). XML (as the name suggests) is a markup language that essentially defines a set of rules that describe something. The "something" could be a protocol, the structure of a document, or any kind of data. XML is designed to be machine readable and human readable (although in my opinion, with bias towards the former ;)).

XML documents use something called a schema which describes the structure of the XML itself, and so you can validate an XML document against a schema to make sure that it is well-formed.

There is no relation between PHP and XML. XML is something that PHP can consume and produce. There is nowhere during processing that PHP consumes or produces XML unless you explicitly tell PHP to do so.

XML is sometimes used as sort a of "glue" that allows dissimilar or disparate systems to communicate with each other, but even that is just one of its functions. For example, PHP can consume XML produced by a program written in another language entirely, or XML produced by some website. PHP can also produce XML which can then be consumed by a program written in another language, or by some other source. As you found from the Wikipedia article, SOAP uses XML and this allows clients written in different languages to consume data exposed by a SOAP service.

Comment: XML can be produced by PHP, as well.

Comment: @PauloScardine True - I will add that!

Answer (score 0):

XML gives a starting point for a lot of technologies, particularly web technologies.

While PHP can be used for other things, its origins are in the web and it is still most heavily used there. As such, it would be sorely lacking if it couldn't deal with such a core web technology as XML. Likewise, it has support for other key web technologies like URIs, and those heavily used with the web like streams and database connections.

Answer (score 0):

XML is only a data format specification. It was once very hipped but has somewhat faded in favor of JSON - it is still VERY popular because there are many protocols using it as the data interchange format.

PHP is generic enough (as a programming language) to generate XML as well as any other data format.

Since XML is such an important data format, every respectable programming language is expected to easily consume XML as well, and PHP is no exception.